# Inserting Wordpress Post via External Script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, insert

I'm trying to insert bulk posts via an external php script:

```
<?php
require_once '/full/path/to/wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';

$title = "some post title";
$content = "some content";
$tags= "tag1,tag2,tag3";
$user_id = 1;


// Create post object
$my_post = array(

   'post_title'    => $title,
   'post_content'  => $content,
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_author'   => $user_id,
   'post_type'     => 'post',
   'tags_input'    => $tags,
 );

$id = wp_insert_post($my_post,true);
?>
```

$id returns 0 and WP_Error is empty.
Post is inserted to DB with right title and content but without tags. It also fails to use wp_insert_terms() to insert tags or other custom taxonomies.

Did i miss a file to include or is there something i didn't set right to work functions properly?

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to load taxonomy.php.. this functionality is handled by wp-load.php

also i would suggest that you put this on first position in your file:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
```

than you can use wp_insert_post() to add the post.. but to add the tags or category and so on you need to use

```
wp_set_post_terms()
```

or

```
wp_set_object_terms()
```

with your recieved $id from wp_insert_post.

for more informations check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18236/attaching-taxonomy-data-to-post-with-wp-insert-post

Comment: i removed taxonomy.php but whatever i try $id from wp_insert_post is always 0 (zero, no wp_error object either), but post is inserted, i don't get it.

Comment: what happens when you remove change wp_insert_post to wp_insert_post($my_post) without the last parameter? are you sure the path to wp-load is correct?

Comment: It is same without 2nd parameter. wp-load path is correct but no luck.

I decided to use page template instead of external script, it's working perfect anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Please include the wordpress database files first.

```
require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
```

and use the following code to insert post dynamically from the external script.

```
 $newIds = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title' => $postCSVContent['1'],
            'post_content' => $postCSVContent['2'],
            'post_type' => 'doors',
            'post_status' => 'publish',        
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_parent' => $parentId
    ));
```

Refer the tutorial that explains how to create and update wordpress post programmatically.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/insert-udpate-wordpress-post-programmatically/